# Qual a melhor maneira de implementar a lógica de autenticação em um aplicativo React Native com Redux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, react-native, redux

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo React Native que utiliza o Redux para gerenciar o estado global. Eu gostaria de implementar a lógica de autenticação no meu aplicativo, mas estou um pouco perdido em relação à melhor maneira de fazer isso.

Eu já tenho um backend que lida com a autenticação, e atualmente estou usando o Firebase Auth para autenticação de usuários no meu aplicativo. No entanto, estou tendo dificuldades para descobrir como integrar isso com o Redux e garantir que o estado da autenticação seja gerenciado de maneira consistente em toda a aplicação.

Minha pergunta é: qual é a melhor maneira de implementar a lógica de autenticação em um aplicativo React Native com Redux? Algumas coisas que gostaria de saber incluem:

```
Qual é a melhor maneira de armazenar o estado de autenticação em todo o aplicativo?
Como posso garantir que os usuários sejam redirecionados para a tela de login quando não estiverem autenticados e para a tela inicial quando estiverem?
Existe alguma biblioteca ou pacote que possa me ajudar a simplificar essa implementação?
```

Qualquer conselho ou orientação seria muito apreciado. Obrigado!

Comment: A pergunta ja tem 3 meses, mas (i) você está usando componentes funcional ou class? (ii) o redux já mantém o estado por toda aplicação, basta criar o `mapstatetoprops` e conectar+exportar a função de seu componente. Se vc tiver algum código iniciado, atualize o post.